# Is there anyway to access the general purpose registers of ARM with C?

Tags: c, linux, arm

I have installed linux 2.6. I wanted to know if there are any drivers to access the GPR port pins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for a `/dev/gpio` file. [This link](http://www.at91.com/index.php?option=com_jfusion&Itemid=57&jfile=viewtopic.php&f=9&t=5275) shows some C code that accesses the GPIO pins. Please note that the exact way this works might differ with different ARM Linux distributions, and you don't give a lot of detail in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the link
I'm trying to access the GPIO pins using mmap. How does one get to know the physical address of the banking register controlling the pin?

Comment: I'm working on a friendly arm mini2440 board with a sc32440 processor

Comment: easy: download the datasheet or the technical reference manual and look for the register description of the gpio block.